# Can't update any page in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, internet-connection

After updating any page in the wordpress site I see the mistake http://joxi.ru/gmvg1LQfLanRJ2 
This problem disappearing if I access Internet through wifi network using the same router, pc and browser. 
Trying different browsers makes no difference.

My colleges from other cities update pages of the site without difficulties.

So I see the problem in the cable Internet connection. Drivers of my Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller is up to date. My router is D-link DIR-615.

Updating pages on other sites including wp ones is processing without problems. However I had the similar one a couple of month ago with opencart theme. But in that case I blamed the theme and removed it.

Thanks for your advices.